# Подпись flutter приложения

Tags: flutter, dart

не получается подписать flutter приложение. Чувствую, что ошибка очень простая, но никак не могу её найти.
Все сделано по https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android
Использую старый ключ jks, которым подписывал другие приложения на java и все работало ( все пароли и имена совпадают)

flutter clean - не помогает
Пробовал собрать через консоль ( flutter build appbundle --release )
Менял расположение jks

При запуске Build App Bundle появляется ошибка

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'. A
> failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Failed to
> read key KeyApp from store
> "C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\key.jks": Cannot recover key

**key.properties**

```
storePassword=primer1
keyPassword=primer2
keyAlias=KeyApp
storeFile=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AndroidStudioProjects\\key.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этой строке

```
storeFile=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AndroidStudioProjects\\key.jks
```

Попробуйте заменить на

```
storeFile=key.jks
```

Сам **jks** файл должен быть по следующему пути

```
yourFlutterProject/android/app/key.jks
```

**key.properties** ожидается, что будет по пути

```
yourFlutterProject/android/key.properties
```

И всё должно работать.

Comment: Абсолютные пути - зло, на другой машине проект просто не запустится, смотрите мой ответ, должно помочь :)

Comment: Появилась другая ошибка  'jarsigner: key associated with KeyAlias not a private key'.  А при размещение ключа внутри проекта это безопасно ?

Comment: Jks как и key.properties должны быть в .gitIgnore

Comment: А по поводу ошибки, вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037262/android-studio-update-bundle-jarsigner-key-associated-with-key0-not-a-private-k

Comment: "Build" -> "Clean project", then "Generate signed ..." again - worked fine for me   Это из первого ответа.